# How do I check if more words are made from the exact same characters in C?

Tags: c, string

I have the following problem: I need to input words until EOF and after to group the words which are made from the exact same characters (not necessarily from the exact same number of characters).

For example:

Input:

`"abc" "acb" "abcabc" "cab" "de" "gh" "ab" "ed" "hg" "abcde"`

Output:

```
"abc" "acb" "abcabc" "cab"
"de" "ed"
"gh" "hg"
```

I will put down what I did so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char **groups, word[30], **store, n = 0, k = 0;
    store = malloc(1*sizeof(char *));
    if (store == NULL) exit(1);
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        if (scanf("%s", word) == EOF) break;
        store[n] = malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
        if (store[n] == NULL) exit(1);
        strcpy(store[n], word);
        n++;
        store = realloc(store, (n+1)*sizeof(char *));
        if (store == NULL) exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", store[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I do not really know how to check the characters. Can you help me out?

**UPDATE**

I tried to do as @jarmod suggested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char **groups, word[30], **store, n = 0, k = 0, *aux;
    store = malloc(1*sizeof(char *));
    if (store == NULL) exit(1);
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        if (scanf("%s", word) == EOF) break;
        store[n] = malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));
        if (store[n] == NULL) exit(1);
        strcpy(store[n], word);
        n++;
        store = realloc(store, (n+1)*sizeof(char *));
        if (store == NULL) exit(1);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", store[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<strlen(store[i])-1; j++) {
            for (int l=(j+1); l<strlen(store[i]); l++) {
                if (store[i][j] > store[i][l]) {
                    aux = store[i][j];
                    store[i][j] = store[i][l];
                    store[i][l] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", store[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<strlen(store[i])-1; j++) {
                if (store[i][j] == store[i][j+1]) {
                    for (int l=j; l<strlen(store[i])-1; l++) {
                        store[i][l] = store[i][l+1];
                    }
                    j--;
                    store[i] = realloc(store[i], (strlen(store[i])-1)*sizeof(char));
                    if (store[i] == NULL) exit(1);
                }
        }

    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s ", store[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirement. What if you have two groups of words from different characters?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: `ab, ba, cd,dc`

Comment: Yes, then you need to group "ab" with "ba". The others are not having the same characters. And another group: "cd" with "dc". I guess making more groups is not the hard part. The hard part is how to check if they are made from the same characters.

Comment: the algorithm will depend on the requirements

Comment: Yes, I know. I updated it for better understanding.

Comment: This sounds like a fun project. I'd encourage you to think about how you would solve this on paper, then devise an algorithm for it, and then implement that algorithm in C. Once you have some code, if it's not working then this forum can help you. You'll get more satisfaction, and gain skills, by solving it this way.

Comment: @jarmod I already know how I would do it on paper. I take the first letter from the first word and check if it is in any other word. Then, if it is, I take the second and check if that is also and so on. The problem is that I do not know how to implement this and if it's the right approach. And also, if let's say we have "abc" and "abcd" there is not enough to check if "abcd" contains "abc", we also need to check if it has any other different characters.

Comment: I would go in the following direction - iterate the words and make a string consisting of a *sorted unique" characters composing it. Then you can have algorithms that differ in complexity to traverse this new data structure

Comment: One way to test if string1 is equivalent to string2, given your definition of equivalence, would be to sort the letters within each word (so "acdba" -> "aabcd") and then remove duplicates (so "aabcd" -> "abcd"). Then you can do simple comparisons for equivalence.

Comment: @jarmod WOW. How I did not think about that? I will try and see if I can make it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jarmod Ok, I tried to do as you said, the problem is that removing the duplicates does not work. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no need for the store[i] = realloc() code because you're simply shortening the strings. Are you also correctly null-terminating the string as you iteratively shorten it? You need to. If you still have problems, then please give us more info than "it does not work".

Comment: @jarmod Well, if I input "abcabc", it orders in into "aabbcc" and then it just stays like that and if I end it I get "Process terminated with status -1073741510 (1 minute(s), 8 second(s))". What do you mean by null-terminating the string?

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/e8HGV9hm (and delete the printf debug statement from that code). C strings are terminated with a zero/null character. Simply shifting characters down the string does not shorten the string - you have to move the zero/null terminator too (or just overwrite the last character of the string with zero like the pastebin does).

Comment: @jarmod Another problem that came in my mind is that if we modify these strings, then how can we add them like they were before after we check if they are the same? I think we need to duplicate them before, check with the duplicates and add the original ones when we group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186877/discussion-between-jarmod-and-ghost).

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use a 26 bits mask for each word so you can group them by mask value.

I have made an implementation, but the actual grouping and display part is not optimized. I does solves your problem tough

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int     main() {
  int       matched = 0;
  int       n_words = 0;
  char**    words = NULL;
  int*      masks = NULL;
  int       max_mask = 0;

  while (1) { // Read until EOF breaks
      char word[30];
      if (scanf("%s\n", word) == EOF)
        break;
      words = realloc(words, sizeof(char *) * (n_words + 1));
      words[n_words] = strndup(word, 30);
      n_words++;
  }

  // Computes a bit mask for each word
  masks = malloc(sizeof(int) * n_words);
  for (int i = 0; i < n_words; ++i) {
    masks[i] = 0;    
    for (int j = 0; words[i][j] != '\0'; ++j) {
      int bit_index = words[i][j] - 'a';
      masks[i] |= (1 << bit_index);
    }
    if (masks[i] > max_mask)
      max_mask = masks[i];
  }

  // Iterate over each possible masks and print all words with this mask
  for(int i = 0; i <= max_mask; i++) {
    for (int w = 0; w < n_words; w++) {
      if (masks[w] == i) {
        printf("%s ", words[w]);
        matched = 1;
      }
    }
    if (matched) {
      printf("\n");
      matched = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a clever way to determine to which group a word belong.

We must create a scheme were each group is uniquely identified by a number. How do we define and differentiate a group: by what letters it contains. Repeating letters don't count (this is a set). So we need a formula to *encode* the set of letters of a group. If we assign each letter a number (starting from `0`) we obtain the id by sum of powers of two (really any base can be chosen, but `2` is the natural choice for computing).

E.g.:

`"abdeae"` The set of letters is `{'a', 'b', 'd', 'e'}`. Their corresponding numbers are: `{0, 1, 3, 4}` and the id is `2^0 + 2^1 + 2^3 + 2^4`.

Because there are `26` letters we can use a 32 bit integer to encode the id. `2^i` corresponds to bit `i` so the alg looks like this:

```
uint32_t letter_mask(char ch)
{
    assert(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z');

    return (uint32_t) 1u << (ch - 'a');
}

uint32_t word_group_id(const char * str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    uint32_t id = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        id |= letter_mask(str[i]);
    }

    return id;
}
```

---

Now that we have an easy way to determine the group of a word you need to create a simplified version of a map where to put the words.

This is my simple quick implementation. Disclaimer: not tested. You must also improve it by adding checks for malloc and realloc.

```
typedef struct Word_map_bucket
{
    uint32_t id;
    char** words;
    size_t words_size;
} Word_map_bucket;

void init_word_map_bucket(Word_map_bucket* bucket, uint32_t id)
{
    bucket->id = id;
    bucket->words = NULL;
    bucket->words_size = 0;
}

typedef struct Word_map
{
    Word_map_bucket* buckets;
    size_t buckets_size;
} Word_map;

void init_word_map(Word_map* map)
{
    map->buckets = NULL;
    map->buckets_size = 0;
}

Word_map_bucket* find_bucket(Word_map map, uint32_t id)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < map.buckets_size; ++i)
    {
        if (map.buckets[i].id == id)
            return &map.buckets[i];
    }
    return NULL;
}


Word_map_bucket* add_new_bucket(Word_map* map, uint32_t id)
{
    map->buckets = realloc(map->buckets, map->buckets_size + 1);
    map->buckets_size += 1;

    Word_map_bucket* bucket = &map->buckets[map->buckets_size + 1];
    init_word_map_bucket(bucket, id);

    return bucket;
}

void add_word(Word_map* map, const char* word)
{
    // get to bucket
    uint32_t id = word_group_id(word);
    Word_map_bucket* bucket = find_bucket(*map, id);
    if (bucket == NULL)
        bucket = add_new_bucket(map, id);

    // increase bucket->words
    bucket->words = realloc(bucket->words, bucket->words_size + 1);
    bucket->words_size += 1;

    // push word into bucket
    bucket->words[bucket->words_size - 1] = malloc(strlen(word));
    strcpy(bucket->words[bucket->words_size - 1], word);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. use `int count[256]` get each char whether in word for each word, for example, for `"abcabc"`, make `count['a'] = 1` `count['b'] = 1` `count['c'] = 1`
2. `qsort` with special compare use `count`
3. output, for each word, if `count` is same，output in a line, if not output next line

The following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
  unsigned char* st;
  int count[256];
};

int compare(const void* x, const void* y) {
  const struct Node* node_x = (const struct Node*)x;
  const struct Node* node_y = (const struct Node*)y;

  for (int i = 0; i != 256; ++i) {
    if (node_x->count[i] > node_y->count[i])
      return -1;
    if (node_x->count[i] < node_y->count[i])
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  unsigned char f[][10] = {"abc", "acb", "abcabc", "cab", "de", "gh", "ab", "ed", "hg"};
  int n = sizeof(f) / sizeof(f[0]);
  struct Node node[100];

  for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    node[i].st = f[i];
    for (int j = 0; j != sizeof(node[i].count) / sizeof(node[i].count[0]); ++j)
      node[i].count[j] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; f[i][j] != '\0'; ++j) {
      unsigned char ch = f[i][j];
      node[i].count[ch] = 1;
    }
  }

  qsort(node, n, sizeof(struct Node), compare);

  int t = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      ++t;
      continue;
    }
    int k = i - 1;
    if (memcmp(node[i].count, node[k].count, sizeof(node[i].count)) == 0) {
      if (t == 1)
        printf("%s ", node[k].st);
      printf("%s ", node[i].st);
      ++t;
    } else {
      if (t != 0)
        printf("\n");
      t = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you telling me that my example is wrong? The problem was to group the strings made from the same characters. I can't group something that does not have a pair, if you understand what I am saying. It's not wrong how you thought about it tho. Also, what you did here is not for a general case.

Comment: @Ghost I get it, and I fix my answer.